# Web Service Call Fails on iPhone Screen Lock

Tags: ios, objective-c

If the iPhone screen locked automatically or annually while I call any Web Service then the connection breaks and its throw unable to connect server message.

Is there any way I can resume the service call or handle screen lock scenario.

Due to this app goes in inconsistent state some time

Comment: Did you find a sollution

Answer (score 1):

When Phone is locked or The App is in background mode. you need to call API as a background service.

Comment: Actually its working fine with Background mode, if I press home button it works proper but it fails on screen lock

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can handle the screen lock scenario.

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```

you can set this when you start calling web service and stop by set value to `NO` when you finished your work.

And if it does not work, then you can put this line in appdelegate's method.

```
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions {
       [UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
       return YES;
}
```

which will disable your automatic screen lock for whole app while running.

Comment: no we can't handle user's events, but we can manage in it appdelegate's applicationDidEnterBackground and applicationWillEnterForeground methods..